# Socket accepting method id like while true

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking

```
TcpListener tcpserver;
Socket serverSocket = tcpserver.AcceptSocket();
```

Here 2nd line is like `while(true)` I mean till it any client gets connected to tcp server
it will not execute any line below it.

What my problem is: I want to accept multiple clients through this tcpserver but based on a flag like `if admin_flag is TRUE` then accept connection otherwise not. And this flag is going to toggle at any time by different thread.

I write this code:

```
while (true)
{
    if(admin_flag==true)
    {
        Socket serverSocket = tcpserver.AcceptSocket(); 
    }
    else
    // do something...
}
```

when I run it once, client is get connected. but when `admin_flag` is toggled i.e set to false it is not going in else part this is because the control remains in Accepting state 
of socket & not executing other part even if it it while(TRUE).

plz guide??

Answer (score 3):

`AcceptSocket` is a blocking method call which means that it will block the thread of execution until it can accept an incoming connection. If no connection is established with your listener then the call will continue to block indefinitely.

You would have to for example either stop the listener or switch to accepting connections asynchronously using the non-blocking `BeginAcceptSocket` or `AcceptSocketAsync` methods.

Comment: How to do that?? i m new to C#

Comment: Here's an example that shows how to use it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx.